# Swap worksheets within the excel workbook c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, swap, worksheet

For example, see the image

[image]

I want to swap the worksheet "Sheet1" to "Sheet3".

My Code using EPPlus:

```
            ExcelPackage masterPackage = new ExcelPackage();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                ExcelPackage pckg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(file));

                foreach (var sheet in pckg.Workbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    //check name of worksheet, in case that worksheet with same name already exist exception will be thrown by EPPlus

                    string workSheetName = sheet.Name;
                    foreach (var masterSheet in masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets)
                    {
                        if (sheet.Name == masterSheet.Name)
                        {
                            workSheetName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", workSheetName, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhssmmm"));
                        }
                    }

                    //add new sheet

                    if (sheet.Name.Contains("MB_STORE_POTENTIALvsWALLET"))
                    {
                        masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(workSheetName, sheet);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(workSheetName, sheet);
                        masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToStart(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            masterPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(resultFile));
```

How to do this? Any suggestion please..

Comment: would you go with an open document library like EPPlus, or Excel COM automation? any requirement/preference/existing code? basically two approaches possible: swap contents as well as sheet names, or execute one or two sheet moves depending on sheet count and relative positions.

Comment: Actually I am generating one excel file from 5 different excels. So the generated excel file which used to have 5 worksheets. I want to swap between these sheets. Currently I used EPPlus to generated the excel..

Comment: EPPlus's MoveToStart method is also not working..

Comment: in EPPlus, the methods on `Workbook.Worksheets` `MoveAfter`, `MoveBefore`, `MoveToStart` and `MoveToEnd` are definitely the way to go. I suspect a problem with the rest of the code or the way you're opening/adding/saving the sheets. could you show some code? when you say, "is also not working" does it mean exception, idling, wrong result?

Comment: Hi, I have given my code using EPPlus, but it is not giving the desired result. Please check it.

Comment: The code you have here appears to be a derivative of the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39229793/3773011), or both this question and that answer are derivatives of something else. Either way, you need to give attribution to where you got the original of the code. It's possible that you originated the code and that other people got it from you having posted it somewhere else, but if so, then that should be explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine:

```
ExcelPackage masterPackage = new ExcelPackage();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    ExcelPackage pckg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(file));
    foreach (var sheet in pckg.Workbook.Worksheets)
    {
        //check name of worksheet, in case that worksheet with same name already exist exception will be thrown by EPPlus
        string workSheetName = sheet.Name;
        foreach (var masterSheet in masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            if (sheet.Name == masterSheet.Name)
            {
                workSheetName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", workSheetName, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhssmmm"));
            }
        }

        //add new sheet
        if (sheet.Name.Contains("MB_STORE_POTENTIALvsWALLET"))
        {
             masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(workSheetName, sheet);
        }
        else
        {
             masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(workSheetName, sheet);
             masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveBefore(2, 1);
        }
    }
}
masterPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(resultFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

If only you need to swap the sheets (I mean content do not required to be processed) then renaming sheet should be simple.

1. Rename the "Sheet1" to "adsf"
2. Rename the "Sheet3" to "Sheet1"
3. Rename the "adsf" to "Sheet3"

Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "adsf"

Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Sheet1"

Sheets("adsf").Name = "Sheet3"